How to purchase Sparpreis ticket without disclosing personal information?

How do you purchase a (Super) Saver’s Fare ticket (Sparpreis) without disclosing personal information or entering additional agreements?
Yesterday I went to the train station trying to pull me a ticket from the vending machine.
It showed only the expensive €500+ options although the Deutsche Bahn website said it was possible to get a €37.8 deal.
I inquired at the Reisezentrum and learned that you must disclose an email address or phone number now!
The vending machine do not provide a way to enter such thus hide the Saver’s Fare options.

I’ve never heard of German train ticket scalpers, but is this a step toward implementing a realname and ID requirement like in China?
It appears to me as such because I cannot think of any sane reason to ask for personal information; it worked for over a hundred years without.

Is there any German legislation mandating that (because Saver’s Fare = long‑distance travel [using ICs and ICEs] = potential terrorist)?
Or did the Deut$che Bahn make that decision on their own without being forced to by legislation?

You can still purchase a ticket in person and pay a ridiculous “service fee” on top of the ticket price.
Are there any negative consequences of providing a fake email address or phone number?
In particular invalidating the ticket comes to mind.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Do not take a big portion of the information out of the question. This invalidate answers already given.


How do you purchase a (Super) Saver’s Fare ticket (Sparpreis) without disclosing personal information or entering additional agreements?

You don't.  Deutsche Bahn (DB) now forces all buyers of Sparpreis tickets to give a phone number or email address.  They claim this is so they can inform people in case of delays or cancellations.
For their tendency to force digital-only (and therefore non-anonymous) tickets, Deutsche Bahn received the Big Brother Awards in 2024.  Not only Sparpreis tickets, but also Bahncard and Deutschlandticket (when ordered from DB) are digital-only, quasi forcing people to use smartphones, which can usually be tracked.  (For the Deutschlandticket, other providers offer non-digital alternatives, but the Deutschlandticket is fundamentally linked to a person.)

Is there any German legislation mandating that (because Saver’s Fare = long‑distance travel [using ICs and ICEs] = potential terrorist)?

No.  This is a DB business decision.
In fact, the Datenschutzbeauftragte (data protection officer) from the state of Hessen has announced he believes the new DB policy is illegal under German law, so the new DB policy may well end up being challenged in court and, depending on outcome, being adapted.

Are there any negative consequences of providing a fake email address or phone number? In particular invalidating the ticket comes to mind.

It does not invalidate the ticket (conductors do not check email addresses), but sometimes DB changes train departures to depart earlier.  If you provide fake contact information and you don't actively look at departure times yourself, you might miss your train.  You should normally still be allowed to take a later departure, but you won't have your seat reservation and if you're travelling far, might not make it to your destination the same day.  I don't know what delay compensation rights you have in this case.  So if you do provide fake contact information, I would strongly recommend to look at departure times by the latest some hours in advance of travel.

(+1) I don't fully get the concern with the email address though, at least from a data protection perspective. I think it's been a few years that discount tickets require providing a name and in true German fashion the terms and conditions explicitly require carrying an ID document within a limited list of state-issued documents, which I always found a bit intrusive. By contrast, it's easy to provide an email address that's not personal data (e.g. from a disposable email address provider like duck.com).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
